# How can I wget if a file has changed?

Tags: linux, wget

I have a cronjob that downloads a PDF file from a remote server.  The file name is always static but I save it into a directory with the date.  The file gets saved as the original save time from the server, however the `-N` switch doesn't seem to work.

I get an error about timestamping can't be used with `-O`.

Is there something I am missing?  I read the man page and can't sort this one out.

```
wget -N -O ~/foo/foo_`date +%Y%m%d`.pdf http://foo.com/blarg/daily_newsletter.pdf
```

Is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) explains it quite nicely:

> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file. If ‘-’ is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion. (Use ‘./-’ to print to a file literally named ‘-’.)
>
> Use of ‘-O’ is not intended to mean simply “use the name file instead of the one in the URL;” rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: ‘wget -O file http://foo’ is intended to work like ‘wget -O - http://foo > file’; file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there.
>
> For this reason, ‘-N’ (for timestamp-checking) is not supported in combination with ‘-O’: since file is always newly created, it will always have a very new timestamp. A warning will be issued if this combination is used.

So, as it says, `-O` is not to rename the output file, but to redirect all of the standard output, for all files downloaded, to `file`.  You'll probably have to download the file and rename it to preserve the timestamp.

Comment: The mtime of the file is not when the file was saved on my server, but when the author of the PDF saved the actual file according to stat.  Access/Change fields report when cron downloaded the file.  Modified shows when the actual file was saved, and `ls -l` shows the modified time as well.  Which is why I thought `-O` and `-N` should work because the actual timestamp is in fact unchanged.  Since `wget` is already in a bash script I can probably sort the rest out by following what you recommended.  Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to download the file from a URL which contains dynamic query string, e.g. `https://domain/file.ext?AWSAccessKeyId=Abc123&Expires=123456&Signature=Xyz789`. The server doesn't support `HEAD` request and doesn't write the `Content-Disposition` header, so I cannot try using the `--content-disposition` option for renaming file together with the `--timestamping` option.

I cannot find a way to download such file only when changed using `wget` or `curl` alone. However, I noticed that the response contains the `Last-modified` header, so I managed to write a bash script to do so:

```bsh
FILE=file.ext
TS_FILE=.$FILE.last_updated
url=$(command_to_get_url)

# create a temp file with server timestamp
last_modified=$(curl -sD - "$url" | head -n 10 | grep -am1 '^Last-Modified' | cut -d' ' -f2-)
touch -d "$last_modified" "$TS_FILE"

# skip if local file is newer
if [[ -f "$FILE" && ! "$TS_FILE" -ot "$FILE" ]]; then
    echo "Skipping download as existing $FILE is newer than that on server."
    exit 1
fi

# download and set timestamp
wget -O "$FILE" "$url"
touch -r "$TS_FILE" "$FILE"
rm "$TS_FILE"
```